# Need help with theme Business (Modern Themes): sidebar issue

Tags: sidebar

I'm using Business theme from Modern Themes (modernthemes.net/wordpress-themes/business/).

I have a "problem" that doesn't seem like a real problem because it is shown in the demo of the theme, so it was built to look like that, but it really bothers me.

Author, category, tag and archive page shows a full width posts and a sidebar below posts.

How it looks like (tags page): [image]

How it should look like (post page): [image]

Can you help me with this sidebar, please?

Comment: The [demo](https://modernthemes.net/theme-demos/?theme=Business) as far as I can tell looks like how you want it to look. This is most likely a css issue where your sidebar or main content is too wide for the grid. However, it's impossible to know without seeing the actual site.

Comment: Thanks for your time, Bryan. Have you checked Blog > Categories > Uncategorized page in the demo? It looks like mine, with sidebar below posts. It's probably a simple fix, but I don't know where to start from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a mistake by the theme developer. They forgot the proper grid classes on the html.

Open `archive.php` in the themes folder or in the editor and change line 13

From this:

```
<section id="primary" class="content-area">
```

To this:

```
<section id="primary" class="content-area col-9-12">
```